# Windows 10: Task Scheduler "Missed task start rejected"

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-10

I have a task in Task Scheduler which runs notepad with the sole purpose of waking the computer at 5am Tues-Sat. Usually it works fine. But every so often (something like once a week) it does nothing. If I look in the Task Scheduler history I get:

> Event ID 153
>
> Task Category = "Missed task start rejected"
>
> General = "Task Scheduler did not launch task "\Dr Bobs
>   tasks\Portfolio Update" as it missed its schedule. Consider using the
>   configuration option to start the task when available, if schedule is
>   missed."

Any ideas why it occasionally misses the task? I have tried changing settings such as "If the task fails, restart every minute" to no avail.

Running on a desktop, Windows 10 Home 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked this out. If I use my Android phone to put the PC on standby, using an app called PC Remote, then I get this problem. If I put the PC to sleep directly via Windows then there is no problem.